# Showing GeoJSON data on overlay

Tags: overlay, geojson, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm trying to show/hide some GeoJSON data on an overlay layer.
I've the data as an object, but not at some server.

If I use the overlay type 'geoJSON', I'm getting a Eror:

```
A base layer must have an url
```

How do I show/hide my data using the overlay show/hide?

The [mixed-layers-overlays-geojson-example](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0603-mixed-layers-overlays-geojson-example.html) is not working for me because it uses remote (xyz-json) data.

Additional information: I've the data in some object that I'm intending to modify/update based on user interaction.

PS: it's probably very simple problem

**Edit**: I made a [plunker of the situation](http://embed.plnkr.co/vvxU4VZXUgRZdg9wedEZ/). It shows the dynamic adding and removing of a path object and some empty functions for the geoJSON objects.

Comment: hey, did you refer to this thread? https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/issues/365

Comment: No, I've a base layer and some other layers (with markers)

Comment: Correction: I've only a bunch of Overlay-layers, but they are working except for the geojson-overlay

Comment: can you show us a live demo somewhere so we can examine the code in question?

Comment: Very very interested by a solution here, I have the same problem

Comment: Hi Bruno, check out the answer i posted and the link within. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

I (my collegue) found some ugly answer: accessing the leaflet layers directly.

I forked the plunker from the description and [added some functions](http://embed.plnkr.co/qGeexSEfJh5CH7it2EKF/preview). See my functions `transformGeoObjToPath` and `geoToLeafletLayer`. In our application we use layers of type 'featureGroup' for additional stuff like selecting, but this is not in the 'solution' example

But the solution is not 'beautiful', because it accesses the leaflet directly.