# Is it possible to use leaflet.js and angular-leaflet-directive together?

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I am trying to create **layergroup** that use data from geojson file with angular-leaflet-directive. but have not found the solution. Is it possible to use leaflet.js to create dynamic layergroup when I am using angular-leaflet-directive?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I asked some questions about [Showing GeoJSON data on overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628893/showing-geojson-data-on-overlay/) because we add and remove the objects during runtime but in the end we accessed the leaflet layers directly.

Check out the [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/qGeexSEfJh5CH7it2EKF/preview). There we add geo objects with some 'name' to specific layers. See the functions `transformGeoObjToPath` and `geoToLeafletLayer` how the data is transformed and added. In our example we use object names 'keyframent' to identify the geojson layer objects for later use.